# Truncate a table in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**Description** : I have a table full of tested data. Sometimes, I want to clear it out for new data. I can perform the truncate in the DBMS App like **MySQL WorkBench**, but I'm trying to achieve it within my application instead.

---

**Goal** : to make a button to truncate a table in a database when on click.

---

Here are my steps :

**1 - Declare a route**

```
Route::delete('visitor/truncate',array('as'=>'visitor.truncate', 'uses'=>'VisitorController@truncate'));
```

---

**2 - Create a `truncate` function in my `VisitorController`**

```
public function truncate()
{

    $visitors = Visitor::all();
    $visitors ->truncate();

    return View::make('visitors.index')
        ->with('success', 'Truncate Done');
}
```

---

**3 - Create a button on my view**

```
 {!! Form::model($visitors, array( 'route' => array('visitor.truncate'),'method' => 'DELETE')) !!}
          <button type="submit"  class="btn bgm-red btn-float waves-effect waves-effect waves-button waves-float"><i class="md md-remove"></i></button>
      {!! Form::close()!!}
```

---

**4 - Test**

When I click on it, it get into my `truncate()` function in my controller, but I keep getting this error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::truncate()

---

Do I need include anything to use `truncate()` ?

Any hints on that will be much appreciated !

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The `truncate` method is part of the Query Builder. However `Visitor::all()` returns a `Collection` instance. You need to build the query using the following:

```
Visitor::query()->truncate();
```

Comment: You can directly use Visitor::truncate() which will internally call the query builder's truncate() method.

Answer (score 90):

the following should work as well,

`Visitor::truncate();`

Answer (score 47):

### From the Laravel Docs

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#deletes says:

> If you wish to truncate the entire table, which will remove all rows
>   and reset the auto-incrementing ID to zero, you may use the `truncate`
>   method:
>
> `DB::table('users')->truncate();`

Comment: This solution is easier to use if your table doesn't have dedicated model class (link tables for example)

Answer (score 18):

### Laravel 8.0 docs

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#delete-statements

With query builder:

```
DB::table('users')->truncate();
```

And with model:

```
User::truncate();
```

Answer (score 6):

another way if you dont have a model class for the table - Laravel 5.4

```
DB::connection(database connection name)->table(table name)->truncate();
```

Answer (score 0):

With this package you could also do it with a Laravel command:

https://github.com/laracraft-tech/laravel-useful-additions#dbtruncate

**Install** via composer:

```
composer require laracraft-tech/laravel-useful-additions
```

This is how it is working:

```bash
php artisan db:truncate users
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to go with that lengthy process you just need to do as follows:-

```
Visitor::truncate();
```

Comment: Please note, there is an identical answer, from many years ago. Be sure to add some value, while answering a question that already has similar or identical solution