# How to use angular $http.delete to empty the whole table?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I am currently using laravel 5.3 with angular.
I have few function such as add / edit / delete posts
now I decided to have another function which deletes all posts with just a click.

Somehow I checked that everything works up to my service part but after that it doesn't seem to be passing to my controller in laravel.

Can someone let me know if I am using the wrong syntax for angular or laravel?

I have this in web.php

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
Route::delete('posts/destroyall', array('as' => 'posts.destroyall', 'uses' => 'PostController@destroyall'));
```

this in my PostController.php

```
public function destroyall() {
    Post::truncate();
    return response()->json(Post::get());
}
```

this for my controller in angular

```
    $scope.destroyAll = function () {
        Post.destroyAll()
            .success(function () {
                // Use the get() created in Post service
                // Gets all the posts
                Post.get()
                    .success(function(getData) {
                        $scope.posts = (getData);
                    });
            })
    }
```

This in my service

```
        destroyAll : function () {
            return $http.delete('/posts/destroyall/');
        }
```

can someone give me an advice please?

Comment: Are You Storing It In Database(Table Data)?

Comment: @ShankarShastri yes, stored in DB so wanted to clear the whole table which is the easiest way to delete all

Comment: Then Just Have A Single Route Request To Your PHP And Then Invoke Truncate SQL Statement And Truncate The Data.

Comment: @ShankarShastri so that's like skip angular and just do it directly from front to back? But wouldn't that make the page refresh though?

Comment: $scope.posts is where you are displaying your posts right?If Yes Then Just Update The $scope.posts to null;

Comment: @ShankarShastri oh that yes, I can get that part but just somehow in DB it wouldn't update. that's why I mentioned up to the point before `return $http.delete('/posts/destroyall/');` I still can try `console.log` but when I try to do anything from the backend nothing happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126683/discussion-between-shankar-shastri-and-wxr).

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054706/truncate-a-table-in-laravel-5 Post::::query()->truncate();

Comment: @Bas I read that page already and no help but I figured what's wrong now

Answer (score 1):

it was a stupid mistake but I think this might happen often.

This is because of laravel's routing positions.

I need my routing to be

```
Route::delete('posts/destroyall', 'PostController@destroyall');
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

I had resource then delete that's why it didn't work.
Switch it around then it works fine now.

Comment: That's probably because in the resource you also can call the delete :) So you can post it to the controller and make use of that method